# How to log response in case of errors in Citrus Framework?

Tags: citrus-framework

Let's have the following test code

```
receive(someEndpoint)
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .validate("$.user.name", "Penny")
    .validate("$['user']['name']", "${userName}"));
```

If one of the validations are failing I see the first validation error.

What I want to see:
All validation errors and the response in case of errors.

Any idea?